# Cannot load KML file

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, layer

Good Day,

Why I cannot load KML file made in My maps to my site ?

here is the code i'm using

```
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), mapOptions),
        json = JSON.parse($.trim($('#json .content').html())).nodes,
        markers = [],
        centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div'),
        centerControl = new ControlesMapa(centerControlDiv, map);
        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
           url: 'http://www.santos.sp.gov.br/mapadeobras/sites/all/themes/mapadeobras/kml/bairros.kml',
           map: map
        });
```

when i tried with the file from example. It worked fine

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
          map: map
        });
```

I have tested the kml file on google validator and it's ok. The kml file is public as I've read here in another post.

Please Help

Comment: would remove some of your trailing commas at end of the line; e.g.  map = new `google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), mapOptions),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Try specifying the center of the area of interest if it does not auto-jump to the region as defined in KML.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {

  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.954785,-46.348161);
  var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 11,
   center: location
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'http://www.santos.sp.gov.br/mapadeobras/sites/all/themes/mapadeobras/kml/bairros.kml',
map: map
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Many  thanks JasonM1. The KML laoded very well. But when I put togheter other code I got error in console for the word "var" before ctaLayer. So I have only removed this word from the original code and It worked fine.